# How to set group of tabs and 1 single terminal in Vim 8?

Tags: vimscript, buffers, terminal, linux

I am a Vim beginner. I know you can do `:tabnew file1 file2` to have Vim open up a bunch of files name file1, file2 spread across as tabs.  I know you can move forward and backward between tabs.  My problem is: when I try to open a Vim terminal using `:terminal`, I can only switch back to 1 of the tab.  For example, if I am in file1, I use `:terminal` , I can only switch back between the terminal and file1, I cannot access file2 unless I close the terminal, which brings us back to the beginning, where we have tabs across the editor. Is it possible to cycle between Vim terminal, file1 and file2? Or I better off just use `:!  some commands` then use that as my way to access the terminal? That is a good idea but due to my work, I would need to see the terminal outputs.  Using `:! some commands` will perform terminal commands, but once you press Enter, you are back to the editor and can no longer see what happens at the terminal.

Please let me know and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How did you switch tabs? if you are using `gt` and `gT` it works just fine.

Comment: Well I saw some posts that say just use Control Shift Up and Down to move.  By gT, you mean letter "g" then "Tab"?

Comment: In normal mode, just type character `g` then `t` to move forward, or `g` then `shift` `t` to move backward, `Ctrl Shift Up` does the same but it's not the vim way since it's not let the hands on the home row.

Comment: Some would say using tabs isn't the vim way. :) Or, at least, using them in ways they weren't intended to be used isn't. (Others dismiss it as just another religious war.) Samplings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs/26710166), [here](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/) and [here](http://eseth.org/2007/vim-buffers.html). (FWIW I used to use them before I really knew vim. Now I can't remember the last time I opened one.)

Comment: I should point out that I _would_ use them if I had a workflow where it made sense. I'm no zealot. But between vim buffers nested inside tmux panes/windows nested inside multiple desktops I have more than enough "organizational units", TYVM. ;)

Comment: @BLayer theyve been helpful for me when working across different stages of a compiler (lexer v. parser/ast v. driver—each tab is different set of files from the same proj). But i agree wholly with the spirit of your comments.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I can see that. And any workflow reminiscent of things done in an IDE lends itself to using tabs. Personally I just use the IDE in those cases, though. (For me that means Java coding, mostly.) Of course, I replace the native editor with a Vim emulator! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move between tabs by type `gt` to move forward and `gT` to move backward in the Normal mode.

Or you can show the buffers (like the opening files) by type the command `:buffers` then choose the index number to open any buffer you want by typing another command `b4` for example to open the first buffer like in the picture.

[image]

Take a look at fzf.vim plugin https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#commands. They provides an easy way to access buffers by just type `:Buffer`.

Comment: Just to add.. you can also type **ls** rather than **buffers**...

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to access `:terminal`. It searches for terminal buffers, if there is none it opens a new one in a new tab. If there are any it uses the first one it found, if that terminal buffer is currently displayed in a window it changes to that window, else it opens a new tab and displays the terminal buffer therein.

**I only used this in NeoVim so far, it should also work in Vim, though**

```
function! TerminalTab()
    " find evey terminal buffer
    let b = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')),
                \'getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype", "ERROR") == "terminal"')
    " if no terminal buffers are available
    if len(b) == 0
        tabnew
        terminal
    else
        " we only care for the first terminal buffer
        let b = b[0]
        let bb = win_findbuf(b)
        " if there is no window in any tab that contains a terminal
        if len(bb) == 0
            tabnew
            buffer b
        else
            " again we only care for the first match
            let bb = win_id2tabwin(bb[0])
            exe 'tabnext'.bb[0]
            exe bb[1].'wincmd w'
        endif
    endif
    " we open a terminal to do something
    startinsert
endfunc
nmap <silent> <leader>s :call TerminalTab()<cr>
```